# fixed landscape mode of webview changes when link opens

Tags: android, webview

In mysimple webview app I made the webview orientation as landscape and the website opens always in landscape ,but when another link in the wesite is opened it comes in the porttrait view only.can anyone please help me to make it always in landscape mode eventhough another link opens.

webview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.webview"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.webview.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.webview.WebActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_web" 
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

In your java After `setContentView(R.layout.webview)`

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Answer (score 0):

set orientation to "sensorlandscape" in androidmanifest file and set the configuration changes.

[Please refer this site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)